# If two strings are contained within the line of a file

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm new to Python, so please bear with me, and apologies in advance if this topic has been covered :)

I'm in the process of writing a script to check a list of SMTP logs from a certain domain. I want to ignore any lines that contain other parts of the SMTP conversation such as DATA or RCPT etc...

Here is the script:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('t:\smtpsvc1')
path = "t:\smtpsvc1" # I have used this variable as os.path.join wouldn't accept the variable 'files'
for f in files:
    fullpath = os.path.join(path,f)
    print(fullpath)
    searchfile = open(fullpath, "r")
    for line in searchfile:
            if ('FROM' and '@somedomain.local' in line):
                print (line)
searchfile.close()
```

The script runs, prints the name of the first file then checks the lines and outputs data like this:

2016-09-28 09:31:50 192.168.106.28 APPSERVER SMTPSVC1 SMTPSERVER 192.168.106.124 0 DATA - + 250 0 139 612 47 SMTP - - - -

This seems to trigger the condition looking for @somedomain.local, but seems to be ignoring the FROM part of the if statement. 
What am I doing wrong?
Cheers in advance

Comment: Do you mean `if 'FROM' in line and '@somedomain.local' in line` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
if 'FROM' and '@somedomain.local' in line:
```

To this:

```
if 'FROM' in line or '@somedomain.local' in line:
```

---

I'm assuming that you want to look for lines which contain **either** one of them.

If you're actually looking for lines which contain **both** of them, then change `or` to `and`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Anth: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)

Comment: Hmm changed to your suggestion, and got a lot of lines containing the following (or very similiar)
2016-09-25 07:18:53 74.125.71.28 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 APPSERVER - 25 MAIL - FROM:<ts_dba@somedomain.com>+SIZE=2389 0 0 4 0 234 SMTP - - - -

So now its evaluating the line and outputing lines with FROM in, but ignoring the somedomain.local part?
Weird?!

Comment: @Anth: Did you read what I wrote at the bottom line???

Comment: Ah that worked! Thank you very much! I'll mark this as answered :)